# Multipart HttpUrlConnection data not receiving

Tags: android, asp.net, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data, multipart

I am wondering here and there from last 2 days. My issue is that I am sending multiple files with some text/plain fields using multipart/form-data.
The issue is that when I am sending data using `HTTPCLient` its working fine but when I am trying to send data using `HTTPURLConnection`, server is not receiving anything, below is my `MultipartUtility`,

```
public class MultipartUtils extends NetworkUtility
{
    private static final String END_REQUEST = "--";
    private String mBoundary;
    
    public MultipartUtils()
    {
        mBoundary = END_REQUEST + "quAxBSd"; 
    }
    public HttpURLConnection getUrlConnection(String URL, String httpMethod,
        String contenttype, String boundry) throws Exception 
{
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (httpMethod.equalsIgnoreCase(HTTP_GET) == false)
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    else
        urlConnection.setDoInput(false);
    
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod(httpMethod);
    
    if (contenttype.equalsIgnoreCase(APPLICATION_MULTIPART))
    {
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundry);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
    }
    else
    {
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contenttype);
    }
    return urlConnection;
}

    public String uploadImagesAddPost(Activity mContext, String URL, String jsonString, ArrayList<ImageListBean> mImageBeanList) throws Exception
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = getUrlConnection(URL, HTTP_POST, APPLICATION_MULTIPART, mBoundary);
        httpURLConnection.connect();
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(dataOutputStream, UTF8),
                true);
        
        addJsonToPart(writer, jsonString);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < mImageBeanList.size(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] imageByteArray = {};
                Uri imageUri = mImageBeanList.get(i).getmUri();
                String imagePath = ImageCaputureUtility.getPath(imageUri, mContext);
                if (!imagePath.equals(""))
                {
                    if (mImageBeanList.get(i).getmType().equalsIgnoreCase(MellTooConstants.IMG))
                    {
                        //For img
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                        
                        imageByteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
                        addFileAsByte(dataOutputStream, "imageview" + (i + 1), imageByteArray, ("imageview" + (i + 1)) + ".jpeg", IMAGE_JPEG);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //For video
                        /* Uploading thumb*/
                        Bitmap bitmap = UtilsMellToo.createThumb(imageUri, mContext);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                        imageByteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
                        addFileAsByte(dataOutputStream, "imageview4", imageByteArray, "imageview4" + ".jpeg", IMAGE_JPEG);
    
                        /* Uploading video*/
                        imageByteArray = MellTooUtil.readFileToByteArray(new File(imagePath));
                        addFileAsByte(dataOutputStream, "video", imageByteArray, "video" + (i + 1) + ".mp4", VIDEO_MP4);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //No need to upload data
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            if (i + 1 != mImageBeanList.size())
                writer.append(mBoundary).append(CHANGE_LINE);
        }
        writer.append(mBoundary + END_REQUEST);
        writer.flush();
        return getResponse(httpURLConnection);
    }

    private void addJsonToPart(PrintWriter writer, String text)
    {
        writer.append(mBoundary).append(CHANGE_LINE);
        writer.append(CONTENT_DISPOSITION + FORM_DATA + NAME + "\"formstring\"").append(CHANGE_LINE);
        writer.append(CONTENT_TYPE + PLAIN_TEXT + CHARSET + UTF8).append(CHANGE_LINE);
        writer.append(CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING + "8bit").append(CHANGE_LINE);
        writer.append(text).append(CHANGE_LINE);
        writer.flush();     
    }

    public void addFileAsByte(DataOutputStream outputStream, String fieldName, byte[] imageByteArray, String fileName, String contentType) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, UTF8),
                true);
        
        writer.append(mBoundary).append(CHANGE_LINE);
        writer.append(CONTENT_DISPOSITION + FORM_DATA + NAME + "\"" + fieldName + "\";" + FILE_NAME + "\"" + fileName + "\"").append(CHANGE_LINE);
        writer.append(CONTENT_TYPE + contentType).append(CHANGE_LINE);
        writer.append(CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING + BINARY).append(CHANGE_LINE);

        writer.flush();
        
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes(CHANGE_LINE);
        
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();
        
    }
}
```

Below is the method, how I am using this class,

```
jsonResponseString = new MultipartUtils()
                                        .uploadImagesAddPost(mContext, AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.SAVE_POST_URL,
                                                mJsonString, mImageList);
```

Below is my ASP side,

```
HttpContextWrapper.Request.Form["formstring"]; //This is returning null
```

Please help me out from this...!!!
Thanks in advance

Below is my request,
[image]

Comment: Please write the reason of down vote....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling approximately 4 days, I found the issue was in the boundry and the new line in the request....!

There should be a boundary and a blank line between text and image part and I was not using it. The blank line is separating the header from the boday of the each part of a `multipart/form-data` request...!